# Trouble identifying the type of widget to expand/collapse an area

Tags: java, android

Consider the widget `hello`:

[image: Hello sample image]

When clicked, it opens the area at the bottom with additional widgets (text, buttons, etcetera):

[image: click Hello sample image]

What is this kind of expand/collapse widget called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to build your whole layout with the text and the buttons, but hide them initially by setting their visibility to gone or invisible. Then in code in the onClick listener of the "hello_text" text view, you can change their visibility to visible.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/hello_text" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/hello_text" />


    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/the_text" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/my_text"
         android:visibility="invisible" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/btn_holder"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:visibility="invisible">
         <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/button_text1" />

         <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/button_text2" />
      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your activity or fragment you can do:

```
      TextView the_text_view = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.the_text);
      LinearLayout ll_btn_holder = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_holder);
      TextView hello_text_view = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hello_text);
        hello_text_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                the_text_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ll_btn_holder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```